# regex in c++ search a sequence

Tags: regex, string, c++11

can any one help me to use regex in c++11
for example i have a string `zoo` and i want to look for the word `zoo subsequently` in another string lets say abc**z**def**o**xyz**o**bs

if its found i want to print found else not found how can i do this using c++

Comment: Insert `.*` between letters of original string, turning it into `"z.*o.*o"`, then construct a `std::regex` from that, and run `regex_search` against the long string. This assumes the original string doesn't contain any characters that have special meaning in a regular expression. Quite frankly, this problem would be much easier to solve without using regular expressions at all.

Comment: Use this [(z)(?:.*?)(o)(?:.*?)(o)](https://regex101.com/r/utLakb/1) formula which groups found word letters into separate groups if you would like to have a clear way to see what word you have found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string a="abczdefoxyzobs";
string b="zoo",r="";
//if your string size is too small add .* by hand if not use for
for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++)
    r=r+".*"+b[i];
r+=".*";
regex e(r);
if(regex_match(a,e))
    cout<<"Found\n";
else
    cout<<"Not found\n";
```